# Как кастомизировать экран приложения под все устройства android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

Вот такая проблема. Есть готовое приложение на android. Приложение работает как для смартфонов, планшетов так и для TV-Android. Но конечно оно должно вписываться как в экран смартфона так и в экран телевизора. Но как мне разделить экраны? Смотрите если распределять экраны по диагонали, то для тв идет все что в папке layout-xlarge, но разница между экранами 4k 50” телевизором и 32” fullhd телевизором очевидна. Тестированием на эмуляторах android-tv, я попробовал распределить разметку экранов тв так: layout-sm500dp hd телевизоры  layout-sm600 2к телевизоры   layout-sm1000 4к телевизоры  layout-normal смартфоны  layout-large планшеты  Вроде даже работало, покрайней мере по эмуляторам, но конечно не все, потому что например 7” планшет упрямо не хочет есть  layout-large а ест layout-sm600, что в принципе даже сам гугл пишет https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes
Что же мне делать неужели ничего нельзя придумать?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать параметр UI Mode при создании файла разметки.(11-й по порядку в Available qualifiers). Там есть вариант Televesion

Comment: спс буду копать

Comment: А не подскажите где эти квантификаторы посмотреть вообще

Comment: Все нашел https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources